# Set object to null, from list

Tags: c#, arraylist, ref

I have a variable, then add that variable to list. If i set list[0] to null, its just removed from list and the variable still stays not null.

And if i set the variable to null, the one in the list stays not null.

```
    var s = new String("Test".ToCharArray()); //Example of class

    var list = new List<String>();

    list.Add(s);
```

A:

```
    s = null;

    Debug.Log( list[0] ); //Test
    Debug.Log( s ); //Null
```

B:

```
    list[0] = null;

    Debug.Log( list[0] ); //Null
    Debug.Log( s ); //Test
```

My actual code is much more intricate with multiple variables and objects, some variables holding an instance to the same object (neither are structs), one has a list with all of the objects.

Doing 'list[0] = null' only empties the 0th spot in that list instead of making that object be null, and i want the object to be set to null too.

I expected that both A and B would make both of them null. Can someone explain why its not behaving like that, and how to make it behave like that?

And since the list holds a reference to 's' , why does 's = null' not change the list item to null?

Comment: That's not how C# works. Sorry.

Comment: So is there no type thats similar to an array of pointers, where i can keep pointers in the list so i can change the actual value of that object from the list?

Comment: You have two variables that host a reference to the object. References variables are just variables that hold a value that is a 'reference' to the memory where tho object is. When you set one variable to null you are just changing the value of this variable, not the value of the other

Comment: The problem I believe is that the string is passed by value not reference, therefore the list still holds the same value.

Comment: [Value vs References Types in C#](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: You can use pointers with unsafe code, but that's not really the C# way of doing things. Typically in C# you pass/use a reference to a memory location. So adding `s` to the list actually copies that reference. Setting a variable to null means that you're no longer pointing that variable at a memory location. It doesn't affect other variables pointing at the same memory that one was pointed at. There are `out` and `ref` keywords which methods can accept if they need to modify where a variable points to, but that only works to modify their arguments. Can you tell us more about what you're doing?

Comment: Yeah i know, structs are value, classes are reference, just didnt expect it to work like this @Steve

Comment: I have a class 'Triangle' which has 3 variables of type 'Vertex'.

I have a list of vertices and the triangles hold references to 3 vertices from that list.

Multiple triangles can hold a reference to the same vertex.

Now if i want to delete a vertex (by its index in the list), i want all of the triangles to set their variable that holds that vertex to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is just not how C# works. In particular, C# does not allow to store references to an object directly, only as part of another object. Hence, the following would work:

```
class Variable<T>
{
   public Variable(T value) { Value = value; }
   public T Value { get; set; }
}

var s = new Variable<string>("Test");
var list = new List<Variable<string>>();

list.Add(s);
```

Then you have A

```
s.Value = null;

Debug.Log( list[0].Value ); //Null
Debug.Log( s.Value ); //Null
```

and B

```
list[0].Value = null;

Debug.Log( list[0].Value ); //Null
Debug.Log( s.Value ); //Null
```

Comment: Any particular reason T is a property and not just a variable?

Comment: @LukaKostic You can make it a field if you like, but it is mostly better to prefer properties over fields for a plethora of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `string` to the `List` you're only passing the value of the item, not the object itself.
One way you could do this is to wrap the `string` inside another object:

```
public class wrapper
{
    public string Str{get; set;}
    public wrapper(str s)
    {
        Str = s;
    }

}
```

By using this object instead, If you update the `Str` property of the object, then it will also be changed in the `List` since, the list is pointing at this class which contains the value.

Here is your example but in use.

```
var s = new Wrapper("Buzz");
var l = new List<Wrapper>();
l.Add(s);

s.Str = null;
```

Comment: does Str need to be a property or can it just be a 'public string Str;' , and does Str have to be a struct or can it be a class ?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a property and I believe it could be a struct.

Comment: If my class 'MyClass' has multiple variables and constructor arguments, do i do 'var s = new Wrapper(new MyClass(arg1,arg2));' ? 

Or would the ' s.Str = null ' then be the same issue as in my question

Comment: If i use a struct ( for the Str variable ) then i cant edit it after the initial construction because it gives an error ' Cannot modify the return value .. because its not a variable '. And if i use a class 'public MyClass Str' if i set it to null 's.Str = null' it behaves same as my questions code. Thats why i asked if it can be a class.

Comment: Do you need to be using a struct, and you can do as you said by having multiple values and constructor arguments, that's fine

Comment: Working fine with a class and passing a new instance as constructor. Georg's answer shows the output and is generic (so its reusable), so ill be accepting his, but i gave both an upvote. Thank you for clarifying.